# Vinca (Madagascar Periwinkle) sprouts dying

Tags: houseplants

[image][image][image][image][image]I have planted vinca plant 45 days ago. My vinca plant sprouts are dying. What to do?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you water it?

Comment: Yes I waterd it.

Comment: Isn't the plant a bit overwatered, with wet feet like in pic, always?. Also, are you giving it sufficient sunlight? Probably waiting for the newly sprouted buds to grow will help. I supposed this is after humidity experiment I suggested you to conduct. If that's so, it's not really wilted, you should allow the older leaves to fall back after remove them from humid container and allow them to burst buds fully. The newer growth will be free of wilt. Just don't overwater them or it'll lead a root rot.

Comment: I'm not sure what I am looking at.  DIs this a cutting?   If so, old leaves will often/usually die, and you will see new growrh - which means its doing exactly what it suspposed to?

Comment: I conducted humid experiment you told me to do. Now I see new sprouts dried. Now two weeks over again I have to cover in plastic bag or not?

Comment: Generally speaking, once you see new growth it means there is a root system and you usually should remove the plastic bag.

Comment: I thought I have to wait to remove plastic bag few more days buds to grow a litle bit.

Comment: After removing the plastic bag sprouts dried as in the first image

Comment: @Sunild Don't apply too much Mancozeb+ Carbendazim for now. Leave it as it is under INDIRECT sunlight. Allow it to grow at peace and don't overwater it. Fertilize it with a weak fertilizer every 2 weeks and then you'll be good to go. Then in summers take the plant outside where it gets plenty DIRECT sunlight like in it's natural habitat. Vincas are very resilient plants and adapt to wide circumstances (even droughts)

Comment: Also, when fertilizing, go for foliar spray fertilizer, your new sprouts will likely benefit from it.

Comment: Okay I will try.

Comment: What is the turquoise stuff I‘m seeing on the soil? And the greyish powder at the top?

Comment: And I would under no circumstances fertilize a plant in that condition. There’s simply not enough foliage to handle extra nutrients.

Comment: @Stephie that isn't a fertilizer, that's a contact+systemic hybrid action fungicide i.e. Mancozeb+Carbendazim. Ofcourse at high doses it burns foliage due to its chelated magnesium content as a coordination compound.

Comment: There is not enough foliage to handle extra nutrients. After removing plastic bag foliage dried

Comment: Allow the sprouts to grow @Sunild and water them only once a day. When your foliage turns to about half the thumb's size use weak fertilizers like banana peel extract or so on. Give it good sunlight, it'll fail to grow without the sunlight, it's adapted to rainy deserts. So they often get full overhead sunlight in their natural habitats.Generally speaking, propagating plants or tricking them to grow involves 1.) Humidification 2.) Bagging. 3.) Adaption. Your results with humidification and bagging were good. You failed to slowly adapt them to your local climatic conditions when you removed bag

Comment: Ideally instead of removing the entire bag at once, you should've very slowly exposed the plants few hours every day (some 2-8 hours each day)  to your local climatic conditions. Removing the entire bag altogether without proper adaption is like going from rainy weather at one moment directly to drought at another moment. That felt like too much stress for your plant. Your vinca will heal that's for sure, stop overcaring now and let those sprout grow to an ideal size, each sprout potentially can form into a branch. Once they reach ideal foliar size, fertilize them to compensate lost nutrients.

Comment: Also, cut off any dead, dried off and decayed foliage (keep the green and neon/ yellow foliage without harming them). It'll reduce the stress on your Vinca greatly.

Comment: Okay I will do.